# How to filter inner Set in Java 8 stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have List with objects

```
 List<FrameworkAdminLeftMenu> menu = getMenuFromDB();
```

each `FrameworkAdminLeftMenu` object has method

```
public Set<FrameworkAdminLeftMenuCategories> getFrameworkAdminLeftMenuCategorieses() {
        return this.frameworkAdminLeftMenuCategorieses;
}
```

and method

```
public String getCssClassName() {
        return this.cssClassName;
}
```

each `FrameworkAdminLeftMenuCategories` object has method

```
public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
}
```

How can I filter all List and Set to get FrameworkAdminLeftMenuCategories object by `getId(1)` ?

For example, something like

```
 List<FrameworkAdminLeftMenu> collect = menu.stream()
                .filter(
                        f -> f
                        .getCssClassName()
                        .contains("adm-content")
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

         List<FrameworkAdminLeftMenuCategories> categs = collect
                .stream()
                .filter(
                        f -> f.
                        getFrameworkAdminLeftMenuCategorieses()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(c -> c.getId() == 1)
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: "Categorieses" plural of a plural? :-)

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking. Do you want a collection of all the categories form all the sets with that ID? In this case, try `flatMap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to aggregate the categories from all the sets and filter the ones with the right ID. In this case, you should use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).

Try something like this (untested, obviously):

```
 List<FrameworkAdminLeftMenuCategories> categs = menu.stream()
        .filter(f -> f.getCssClassName().contains("adm-content"))
        .flatMap(f -> f.getFrameworkAdminLeftMenuCategorieses().stream())
        .filter(c -> c.getId() == 1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Uncompilable code on .flatMap(f -> f.getFrameworkAdminLeftMenuCategorieses())

The type of <R>flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>) is erroneous
  where R,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)
    T extends Object declared in interface Stream

Comment: @ArthurKhusntudinov I think I missed a `.stream()` at the end of the `flatMap` line. Does it work now?

Comment: tobias_k, what you mean with phrase ""Categorieses" plural of a plural"? Is my structure of Entity incorrect?

Comment: @ArthurKhusntudinov No, I just stumped on that word, and it seemed that each of those `Categories` object aggregates multiple categories (as 'categories' is the plural of 'category'), and thus `Set`s of 'categories' are consequently 'categories-es', i.e. the "plural of a plural" ;-)